# Ayuda con eliminar un registro de una tabla html, después de resultado deActionResult c#

Tags: html, jquery

Quiero eliminar la fila de una tabla html después de eliminado de la base de datos.

1. al presionar el botón de eliminar, que se muestre de la siguiente manera

   ```
   <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
   <span class="fa fa-cog">&nbsp;</span><span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

   <li><a href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Ofertas", new { @id = 
   @item.MtoOfertaId })' title="Editar Información"><i class="glyphicon 
   glyphicon-edit"></i>Editar</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" onclick="DeleteOferta(id=@item.MtoOfertaId)"><span 
   class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Eliminar</a></li>                                
    </ul>
    </div>
   ```

   me muestra una venta show modal preguntando si quiero realmente eliminar el registro

   ```
   var DeleteOferta = function (Id) {
   $("#DeleteOferta").val(Id);
   $("#DeleteConfirmation").modal("show");
   }
   ```

   código de la vista eliminar

   ```
       <div class="modal fade" id="DeleteConfirmation">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                   <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                   <h4>Eliminar Propuesta Técnico-Económica</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                   <h4>Estas Seguro de Eliminar la propuesta presendata por el proveedor:</h4>
                   <h3><input type="hidden" id="DeleteOferta" name="DeleteOferta"></h3>                    
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="r">Cancelar</a>
                   <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="ConfirmDelete()">Confirmar</a>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. al presionar el botón de confirmar se ejecuta la siguiente función que elimina el registro de la base de datos

   ```
   var ConfirmDelete = function (){

   var id = $("#DeleteOferta").val();

   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: _urlBase + "Ofertas/Delete?id=" + id,        
       success: function (result) {            
           $("#DeleteConfirmation").modal("hide");


           swal('Hecho', 'el registro fue emilinado exitosamente', 'success');

       },
       error: function (xhr, status, error) {
           alert(xhr.responseText);
           $('#submit').html('Guardar Propuesta');
           var IsValid = false;
       }
   })
     }
   ```

   hasta aquí sin problemas. Lo que quiero es que después del success que retorna el AJAX, eliminar esa fila de la tabla HTML, la cual tiene una estructura más o menos así

   ```
   <tr id="6298">
               <td><img class="expand" src="/Content/images/plus.png" orderid="6298"></td>
               <td class="col-sm-3">ABAMCU, S.A. DE C.V.</td>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>060  004 0109 11 01</td>
               <td> ABATELENGUAS DE MADERA, DESECHABLES. LARGO. 142.0 MM. ANCHO. 18.0 MM.</td>
               <td>$1,580.00 </td>
               <td>-10.15 </td>
               <td>3,000</td>
               <td>6,000 </td>
               <td>
                       <div class="dropdown">
                           <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                               <span class="fa fa-cog">&nbsp;</span><span class="caret"></span>
                           </button>
                           <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

                               <li><a href="/Ofertas/Edit/6298" title="Editar Información"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>Editar</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#" onclick="DeleteOferta(id=6298)" id="6298"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Eliminar</a></li>                                

                           </ul>
                       </div>
           </td>
       </tr>
   ```

¿Creen que me puedan echar una mano?

Answer (score 1):

Vas por el camino correcto, lo que te queda es ocultar la fila de la tabla en el evento success. Actualice tu código dentro del evento success buscando el tr con el id que definiste de ejemplo.

Uso de **hide()** para ocultar la fila

```
var ConfirmDelete = function (){

var id = $("#DeleteOferta").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: _urlBase + "Ofertas/Delete?id=" + id,        
    success: function (result) {            
        $("#DeleteConfirmation").modal("hide");

        $('table tr#' + id).hide();

        swal('Hecho', 'el registro fue emilinado exitosamente', 'success');

    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        $('#submit').html('Guardar Propuesta');
       var IsValid = false;
    }
});
}
```

Uso de **remove()** para quitar definitivamente la fila del DOM

```
        $('table tr#' + id).remove();
```

Saludos

Comment: que tal muchas gracias, funciona a la perfección pero eso solo oculta el registro, hay alguna forma de eliminarla definitivamente alfo asi como remove.

Comment: si obvio, podes usar remove() en vez de hide() para quitarlo definitivamente! Actualice mi respuesta!

Comment: Excelente muchas gracia amigo